# Problema com Alinhamento de Tabelas

Tags: html, css

Eu já revisei o HTML várias vezes, mas acho que deve ser algo de errado no meu CSS.
O posicionamento que usei para as imagens foi:

```
/*Produtos*/
.fsResDir{
    width:280px;
    height:280px;
    float:right;
}
/*Forma de Pagamento*/
.fsResEsq{
    width:240px;
    height:280px;
    float:left;
}
```

E aqui está uma imagem de como ele fica:

[image: Queria colocar Forma de Pagamento ao Lado de Produtos]

Comment: Poste o código Html para podermos ajudar

Comment: Coloque o código HTML/CSS!

Comment: quase que aposto que é por causa do tamanho da `div parent` que não é o suficientemente larga para que possa disponibilizar os elementos `child`  lado a lado.

Comment: Exatamente isso kk